# Is there a way I can consume Google PubSub message using synchronous pull in Apache Beam job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, publish-subscribe, apache-beam-io

I have already gone through the client library provided by google in the below doc. The given client library is just to poll the message from PubSub, But it will not poll continuously until we create the Unbounded Source Connector.
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#synchronous_pull

Since the source connector I'm trying to build is Unbounded source,For that I need to take care of Checkpoint Marker, implement PubSub reader, PubSub split source and implement ACK and NACK logic and I believe it will take a good amount to time to create my own Unbounded source connector. Right now PubSubIO(Beam api) only supports asynchronous pull. So is there any way I can just implement ACK n NACK logic logic on top of PubSubIO api provided by Apache Beam. Is there any kind of already developed api which is more suitable for this kind of use-cases.

With synchronous pull, you can acknowledge the intended message and NACK the consumed message in case of any parsing failure.

Comment: What's your issue with async poll? the beam job run, pull all the messages and stop? Do you want an endless job?

Comment: With synchronous pull, you can acknowledge the intended message and NACK the consumed message in case of any parsing failure, so that's the reason I'm trying to use synchronous pull. With async pull, as soon as data consumed by PubSubIO it acknowledge all the message ID @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Ok, and you want to NACK the message to leverage the dead letter topic in PubSub subscription, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right!! @guillaumeblaquiere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature that you expect doesn't exist, and should not exist.

The current behavior, the async pull, get the message and as soon as the message is persisted (in the worker or sink in the pipeline, the first of both), the message is ACK.

In your case, you expect to ACK manually the message according with the pipeline processing. However, you are [limited to 10 minutes to ACK your messages with PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/modifyAckDeadline). Imagine if you build a pipeline with windows of 15 minutes (or more). You need to wait the end of the processing  of the windows to ACK the messages; impossible!

The correct design, in your case, is to manage your errors in your pipeline.